# How to Keep Specific Row Distance between Two Tables

Tags: excel

I have two tables in a sheet and I want to keep a specific distance between them, say a distance of 3 Rows, just like in the attached picture, meanwhile, I keep adding data in the new row **without** **adding** the row and Excel automatically maintain the distance between two tables, or in other words, every new row is added automatically, just by entering the data, while maintaining the specific distance between the two tables.

[image]

So far I didn't find any solution of this upon searching the web.

Comment: I am curious what is the purpose of that? maybe you are trying to achieve something that could be done in a different way.  For example, using Excel Table, you can isolate both ranges of data.

Comment: @David When I type any new data in a new row, the newly typed-in row automatically adds to the table, why not keep them automatically distanced, for the look and yes also to keep the data of the two tables *automatically* separated.

Comment: I see @Tayyab, it would be a nice feature to have in Excel, for example for having a summary table after the end of the raw data, but that feature Excel doesn't have it. What you can do is to use `VSTACK` to achieve it. It will generates both on the fly, but it is a very basic stuff for ordering the information. Then you need to define all formatting via conditional format. The other way could be to use `OFFSET` to place the second table taking into account the total number of rows of table 1